# Writing or flushing a file to asynchronous NFS with c++ ofstreams

Tags: c++, asynchronous, nfs, ofstream

We have a project where multiple nodes writes a data to a file in sequence and the file resides on NFS.

We were using synchronous NFS before so the flush to file streams just worked fine. Now we have asynchronous NFS and its not working. Not working in a sense obviously the caching comes into picture and other nodes doesnt see the changes made by a particular node.

I wanted to know if there is a way to forcefully flush the data from the cache to disk. I know this is not efficient but it will get things working until we get the real solution in place.

Comment: ofstream has no idea of the underlying filesystem. May be the sync(2) system call may help. But it synces all outstanding file buffers.

Comment: I would guess a call to `flush()` would result in an underlying call to `fsync()` or an `ioctl()`.  Maybe run an strace to make sure it does?  If so, possibly `sync()`?  If not, possibly get the file descriptor from `rdbuf()` and explicitly call `fsync()` or an `ioctl()`?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem using NFS with VxWorks. After some experimentation I've found a way to surely flush data to the device:

```
int fd;
fd = open("/ata0a/test.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREATE);
write(fd, "Hallo", 5);
/* data is having a great time in some buffers... */
ioctl(fd, FIOSYNC, 0);   // <-- may last quite a while...
/* data is flushed to file */
```

I've never worked with ofstreams neither do I know if your OS provides something similar to the code shown above...

But one thing to try is to simply close the file. This will cause all buffers to be flushed. But be aware that there may be some time between closing the file and all data being flushed which your application does not see since the "close" call may return before the data is written. Additionally this creates a lot of overhead since you have to re-open the file afterwards.

If this is no option you can also write as much "dummy-data" after your data to cause the buffers to fill up. This will also result in the data being written to the file. But this may waste a lot of disk space depending on the size of your data.